# Does a function $f$ that satisfies $f(2x+y)=f(x+1)+f(y)+4xy$ for all $x,y$ exist?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Does a function $f$ that satisfies $f(2x+y)=f(x+1)+f(y)+4xy$ for all $x,y$ exist?

I was able to figure out some specific values of such a function by plugging in certain numbers, for instance using $x=0,y=1$ I found that $f(1)=0$.  Similarly, I found the values of $f(0)$ by using $x=1,y=0$ and $f(2)$ using $x=-1,y=2$.  But I can't find the entire function...

Comment: I found f(1)=0 when x=0, y=1, f(0) when x=1, y=0, f(2) when x=-1, y=2
But I can't find the entire function.

Comment: you should have edited that comment into the body of the question, making it clearer at a glance that you have at least attempted the problem.

Comment: Usually, for these problems to show the function doesn't exist the strategy is to find some $a$ such that by following one line of logic you get $f(a)$ is equal to one thing while following a different line of logic you got that $f(a)$ is equal to something else, providing the contradiction you need to show the function can't exist.

Comment: Is this $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$? Or something else perhaps?

Comment: Could you include the of $f(0),$ and $f(2)$ that you found?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose such $f$ exists. I found that $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 0, f(2) = 8$.

With $x=1, y=1$,
$$ f(3) = f(2) + f(1) + 4 = 12$$

With $x=1, y=2$,
$$f(4) = f(2) + f(2) + 8 = 24 $$

With $x=2, y=0$,
$$ f(4) = f(3) + f(0) + 0 = f(3) = 12$$

Contradiction.

Comment: Omg yes, thanks for the catch. Luckily the proof still holds!

Comment: Or, I thought that this function might be well-defined when x>2 and x<2 separately. But I cant make any sense.. Thank you

Comment: hanks. How about adding "when y=0" ? Then the equation becomes f(2x)=f(x+1). I read some question on this site. This f can be f(x)=g(log_2 (x-2)) when function g is a Periodic function with unit period.